# Pandas function for generating series from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to generate a `Series` by iterating over a `DataFrame` row by row, using the values from two columns. Something like this:

```
race_cats = ('White', 'Black', 'Hispanic', 'Other')
def raceParse(row):
    if row.hispan != 'Not Hispanic':
        return 'Hispanic'
    elif row.race == 'White':
        return 'White'
    elif row.race == 'Black/Negro':
        return 'Black'
    else:
        return 'Other'
df['race4'] = df.map(lambda r: raceParse(r)).astype('category', ordered=False, categories=race_cats)
```

This doesn't work, obviously, as `DataFrame` doesn't have a `map` method. `apply` and `applymap` work element-wise, not row-wise. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Can you add sample of your `DataFrame` (5,6 rows)?

Comment: apply can work row-wise (`df.apply(raceParse, axis=1`) but this may not be the best way (apply is not very fast). I agree that a sample would be good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve your desired results using `loc` as follows:

```
# Sample data.
df = pd.DataFrame({'hispan': ['Not Hispanic', 'Not Hispanic', 'Hispanic'], 'race': ['White', 'Black', 'Other']})

>>> df
         hispan   race
0  Not Hispanic  White
1  Not Hispanic  Black
2      Hispanic  Other

df['race4'] = 'Other'
df.loc[df.race == 'Black', 'race4'] = 'Black'
df.loc[df.race == 'White', 'race4'] = 'White'
df.loc[~df.hispan.isin(['Not Hispanic']), 'race4'] = 'Hispanic'

>>> df
         hispan   race     race4
0  Not Hispanic  White     White
1  Not Hispanic  Black     Black
2      Hispanic  Other  Hispanic
```

You can then convert the column to categoricals if that is what you desire:

```
df['race4'] = pd.Categorical(df.race4, categories=['White', 'Black', 'Hispanic', 'Other'])
```

Note that the order of the `loc` assignments is important.  It is equivalent to your `if row.hispan != 'Not Hispanic': ... elif` structure.  By having the test for Hispanic last, it takes precedence over the `race` column.

I believe the reply above is what you want.  In terms of what you asked for, there is an `iterrows` method:

```
def race_parse(row):
    if row.hispan != 'Not Hispanic':
        return 'Hispanic'
    elif row.race == 'White':
        return 'White'
    elif row.race == 'Black/Negro':
        return 'Black'
    else:
        return 'Other'

df['race4'] = [race_parse(row) for _, row in df.iterrows()]
```

Comment: I was trying this on a test dataset. It takes 1.05ms on a 10k dataset vs 187ms for apply.

Comment: This is perfect. I tried both methods (a syntax error meant I thought the original one didn't work). I'm curious, though, why the `iterrows` method is unusably slow. My dataset is only ~1m rows; I gave up on iterrows after about four or five minutes, while the .loc method finished more or less instantly. Is it just to do with shifting between Pandas data structures and a standard Python list?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use iterrows generator over your dataframe. This gives index and each row as a series.

```html
for index,row in df.iterrows():
  """
  rest of the code
  """
```